# Arrays and random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

generate 1,000,000 Math.random() integers from 0 to 37 and calculate the percentage that each number appears

```
package arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class arraysintro {

public static void main(String[] args){

    int numValues = 1000000;
    int[] array = randomArray(numValues);
    printArray(array);
}

public static int[] randomArray(int n) {
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = randomInt(0, 37);
    }
    return a;
}

private static int randomInt(int i, int j) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int abc = random.nextInt(37);
    return  abc;
}

public static void printArray(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Hi so I did most of the code everything works.  I can get the 37 randomized 1 to 1000000 numbers but, I can't get the percentage for them.  I tried creating a variable in the Random Int that would create the percentage but, since I can't create a double how do I approach this?

Comment: You have misunderstood the question.  It is asking for 1000000 numbers in the range of 0 to 37; not 37 numbers in the range of 1 to 1000000.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't create a double"?

Comment: Sorry about that otherwise how do you write the percentage? @DavidWallace

Comment: There is an error @ScottHunter

Comment: Well, I'd use an array to keep track of how many times each number comes up.  After each random selection, increment the appropriate element of the array.   Then at the end,   you can turn them all into percentages.

Comment: @user7214716: Then maybe you should show how you tried, and someone can help you fix it.

Comment: Don't create a new `Random` every time. That makes it not-random.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do. Once you've generated the 1000000 numbers and stored them in the array, use a `HashMap` to count how many of each number there is.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
int[] a; //initalzie this;

for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++) { 
   if(map.containsKey(i)) map.put(i, map.get(i) + 1); 
   else map.put(i, 1);
}
```

Now just loop through your map's keys and divide by the total amount of keys.

Alternatively:

Just use an array of 37 elements.

```
int amounts  = new int[38]; 
double percents = new double[38];
for(int i  = 0 ; i< a.length; i++) { 
   amounts[a[i]]+=1; 
}
for(int i = 0; i < 38; i++) {
   percents[i] = ((double)amounts[i]/(double)a.length) * 100.0; //percent is the number of occurances 
   // divided by total amount of numbers (and * 100 to convert from decimal to percent)
}
```

The HashMap solution is more reusable but the array solution will work for this code and is more simple.

Comment: A `HashMap` seems a bit overkill; an array of 37 elements would do the trick.

Comment: @ScottHunter true, but hash map has the nice get/put methods and the iterators and stuff. Doesn't matter honestly. I'll edit the array thing in there.

Comment: Careful with that integer division there

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the array you could keep track of the number of each integer you get by keeping them in a Map where the key is the random integer that is generated and the value is the number of times it comes up. If you don't want to use a map you could use another array and use the index portion of the array as the key and the value as the count of the number of times that integer has been generated.

Comment: Yup, looks like you beat me by 5 minutes and gave a much more detailed answer. Use Ashwin's answer instead of mine.

Comment: Thanks hmm. Idk if that worked for the OP or not, they never responded or accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @Ashwin said, but I would use an `AtomicInteger` instead for the value of the map.

For example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

int[] numbers;
Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> counts;

for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
    int r = random();
    numbers[i] = r;

    if (!counts.containsKey(r))
        counts.put(r, new AtomicInteger());
    counts.get(r).incrementAndGet();
}
```